# Can we differentiate the expected value wrt the random variable

Tags: probability

Can we differentiate the expected value wrt the random variable? That is, $\frac{dEf(x)}{dx}$, where $x$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that if $x$ is the only random variable (and the expectation is over x), then $Ef(x)$ is not a function of $x$ any more. Therefore, $\frac{dEf(x)}{dx}=0$.

If you would like to take the derivative with respect to some other parameters (e.g. a parameter $\theta$ of the distribution function $p_{\theta}(x)$ or the function $f_{\theta}(x)$) then you can use the Leibnitz method for integration if it applies (i.e. you functions are regular, etc.).